# How to wrap ncurses's printw function?

Tags: c++, ncurses

I'm learning how to use ncurses, and wanted to use RAII to automatically init and end window:

```
class CWindow
{
public:
   CWindow() {initscr();}
   ~CWindow() {endwin();}
};
```

This is basic idea of CWindow class. It works only for stdscr now, so using functions like addch(), printw(), etc. isn't a problem. However, this class will eventually be used to represent ncurses windows(WINDOW*). It would be intuitive to add member functions like print, so that instead of using

```
wprintw(win.getWin(), "str %i", someVar);
```

one could write

```
win.print("str %i", someVar);
```

I looked in web, but it seems to me that only cstdio's prinf and similar functions have been wrapped. And cstdio provides an easy way, with function that accepts va_list. However, ncurses doesn't have this set of functions.

To be honest, I'm rather using C++ then C, so my C knowledge isn't excellent. I've also not created any variable argument list functions. I tried naive approach:

```
void print(const char* str, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, str);
    printw(str, args);
    va_end(args);
}
```

However, it doesn't work. I also tried to incorporate variadic macros like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20639632/how-to-wrap-printf-into-a-function-or-macro) thread, but it doesn't work for me. I may be doing it wrong though.

Anyway, how may I achieve this?

Comment: look for "variadic templates", or better yet, make your CWindow class a kind-of-iostream class and use inserters and extractors (`operator <<` and `operator >>`) ...

Comment: I've also seen variadic templates, but they said that variadic template will create separate function for each set of arguments(because this is how templates work). Therefore, it's uneffective regarding code size. I also thought about operator<< and >>, but I want to keep the interface consistent, and I want to use functions mvprintw(const char* str, ...), which moves cursor to (y, x), and then prints str there.

Comment: With sufficient optimization, your variadic template call should be inlined to the original `mvprintw` or `printw` calls and the problem is moot. Anyway, see my answer below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost in the right path to do what you want, just change

```
printw(string, args);
```

for

```
WINDOW *win = initscr();
// ...
vwprintw(win, string, args);
```

Comment: EDIT: Okay; it's actually vwprintw; printw doesn't have its v function... Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 2):

The answer by @massa can be improved:

- while ncurses accepts `vwprintw`, the preferred form is `vw_printw`.
- it is not necessary to use the return value from `initscr`; the `stdscr` variable holds the same value.

With those fixes:

```
void print(const char* str, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, str);
    vw_printw(stdscr, str, args);
    va_end(args);
}
```

Further reading:

- [vwprintw - print formatted output in window ***(TO BE WITHDRAWN)***](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcurses/vwprintw.html)
- [vw_printw - print formatted output in window](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcurses/vw_printw.html)
- [stdarg.h - handle variable argument list](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/stdarg.h.html)
- [PORTABILITY](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_printw.3x.html#h2-PORTABILITY) note in ncurses' manual page

Comment: vw_printw returns an int with OK or ERR that could be beneficial for this print function wrapping it to return as well.