# Replacing function call (and not declaration) with define C

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I try to use define to replace function call, but I can't find how to replace only the call and not the declaration.

IE:

```
#define test(); printf("worked\n");

void test()
{
printf("how sad ?\n");
}

int main()
{
test();
}
```

I can't create my define after the function (project rules)

The problem is : I expected the semicolon after "test()" in the define to replaces only the call, but it replaces also the declaration.

I tried to google and nothing on that, is it really possible ? It's weird that it is not taking the literal expression.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A few things to note:

- `#define` doesn't *require* braces `()` - only use them if you need to handle parameters
- The syntax doesn't include a semicolon: `#define test printf`
- Calling a function like `printf()` like this (somewhat obscured) can be risky, especially if the caller doesn't expect that their string is used as a format string. Prefer `#define test(msg) printf("%s", msg)`
- After a `#define test ...`, the pre-processor will **dumbly** replace *all* instances of `test` - thus the function declaration will actually read `void printf("worked\n"); { ... }`

The result should be either:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define test(msg) printf("%s\n", msg)

void main(void) {
    test("hello");
}
```

or:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void test(const char *msg) {
    printf("%s\n", msg);
}

void main(void) {
    test("hello");
}
```

---

If you are trying to use a `#define` to redirect a function call, then you must use a different symbol... for example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

/* Comment / uncomment this to change behaviour */
#define REDIRECT_TEST

#ifdef REDIRECT_TEST
#  define my_test(msg) printf("REDIRECTED:%s\n", msg)
#else
#  define my_test      test    
#endif

void test(const char *msg) {
    printf("%s\n", msg);
}

void main(void) {
    my_test("hello");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sadly, my project really restrict me and I can't use your solution. I will have to do it manually.

Comment: `#define test(); printf("worked\n");` actually means that when you write `test()` it will output `; printf("worked\n");` (notice that extra semicolon)... (or am I wrong?)

Answer (score 1):

printf have a "variadic arguments". Sometimes уou will have a problem if you wont use any solution from that q/a: ["How to wrap printf() into a function or macro?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20639632/how-to-wrap-printf-into-a-function-or-macro)

Some tip like this, for example:

```
#define MY_PRINTF(...) printf(__VA_ARGS__)
```

or this:

```
#define MY_PRINTF(f_, ...) printf((f_), ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

Answer (score 0):

you should have the define at a separated header file. and the define shall not include the semicolon.
so your code shall look like this:

replace_test.h:

```
#define test() dummy_test()
```

test.h:

```
void test();
```

test.c:

```
void test()
{ your test code}
```

dummy.c:

```
void dummy_test()
{
 your dummy code here (printf("worked!"); etc.
}
```

program.c:

```
//decide which behavior you want, either include replace_test.h or test.h header
#include "replace_test.h"
//#include "test.h"

int main()
{
   test();
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why do you think the answer is completely wrong???
as far as I know, this the common way to use mocks at c with macros. having the define at a header, and using the dummy header as needed.

Comment: You did macro with name `test` and then function with the same name `test`. what?

Comment: it is OK to have a macro and a function with the same name. It would cause problem only if the file test.c or test.h have include to replace_test.h. 
at the using code (program.c), the user can decide whether to include the real test.h header, and really call the function test(), or to include the replace_test.h header, and have the code which call 'test()' replaced with a call to 'dummy_test()' method.

Comment: BTW, regarding mock methods I mentioned before, there is one way doing this with macros, as I mentioned, and another way doing this using function pointers, directing pointers to dummy implementations as needed.

Comment: Then explain properly.

Comment: I wrote what each file (header file or source file) shall contain; having title like test.h: and then the code.
I think this explains the macro usage here. if you now think the answer is ok, please change its score.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an excerpt from my unit test framework. I believe this does what you want...

```
void *(*old_calloc)(size_t, size_t) = calloc;
#define calloc unit_calloc
void *unit_calloc(size_t num, size_t size) {
    ...
    void* retv = old_calloc(num, size);
    ...
    return retv;
}
```

This allows me to redirect a call to `calloc()` without modifying the code that I am trying to test.