# How I can custom fprintf for enable disable

Tags: c++, debugging

I want to customize `fprintf` function for enable/disable Logging

My project use Makefile.

```
#define ENABLE_LOG 
void log(fmt, ...){
  #ifdef ENABLE_LOG
    va_list vargs;
    va_start(vargs, fmt);
    fprintf(stderr, vargs);
    va_end(vargs);
  #endif
}

log("Test"); # build error
log("TEST %d", 1); # build error
```

How I can create custom `log` function that can enable/disable  with `ENABLE_LOG`

Comment: What doesn't work with the above?

Comment: Please create a [mcve] and explain what exactly isn't working. The only thing that stands out to me is that `fmt` needs a type, probably `const char* fmt`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20639632/how-to-wrap-printf-into-a-function-or-macro

Comment: To add to the comment by @alterigel, you also can't have generic statements outside of functions, like the shown calls to `log`.

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And when asking about build errors, include the actual errors in your question, copy-pasted (as text) in full and complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`vfprintf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/vfprintf). Also, I would make an empty macro that would avoid a call to an empty function.

```
#define ENABLE_LOG 
#ifdef ENABLE_LOG
void log(const char *fmt, ...) {
    va_list vargs;
    va_start(vargs, fmt);
    vfprintf(stderr, fmt, vargs);
    va_end(vargs);
}
#else
#define log(fmt, ...)
#endif
```

Also, note that there is already a C++ function named [`log`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log). You might consider a different name (especially if you use the dreaded `using namespace std;` - even though your code looks like pure C.)

Comment: Empty macro is a dangerous thing. Better make it a void expression: `#define log(fmt, ...)   (void)(0)`

Comment: @IgorG I've not heard that. What makes it dangerous?

Comment: unpredictable use scenarios do. Some code might get broken (or get interpreted in a different way) if a non-empty sequence of tokens is replaced with an empty token sequence. For example, if some client programmer wanted to log his expressions as they are calculated, he may have `#define LOGGED(expr)   (log("Evaluating " #expr), (expr))`. Which would expand to an invalid expression `(, (expr))` if `log()` is empty. This example is rather exotic, I admit. However, to be on the safe side, it's better to have `log()` that always expand to the same type.