# How to prepend formatted data to an printf() call

Tags: c, printf, variadic-functions

I want to implement a variadic function which behaves like printf, except that it prints some prefix. For example, let's say I want the prefix to be the value of `time(0)`. if I call:

```
wrapped_printf("Hello, world %d", 5678);
```

I'll expect something like:

```
1571441246 Hello, world 5678
```

as the output.

Obviously, replacing the format string is not a big deal; it's the variadic business that's giving me trouble. Should I implement this as a function taking `...`? Taking a `va_list`? And how do I prepend my extra arguments?

This is what I have right now. It compiles and runs (it's valid C89 even...), but the extra arguments get messed up.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <time.h>

int wrapped_printf(const char* format_str, ...)
{
        static const char* const prefix = "%d ";
        static const size_t prefix_length = 3;

        va_list ap;
        size_t format_string_length = strlen(format_str);
        char* const prefixed_format_str = malloc(format_string_length + prefix_length + 2);
                /* 1 for the trailing '\0' and 1 for a line break */
        if (prefixed_format_str == NULL) { exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
        strncpy(prefixed_format_str, prefix, prefix_length);
        strncpy(prefixed_format_str + prefix_length, format_str, format_string_length);
        prefixed_format_str[prefix_length + format_string_length] = '\n';
        prefixed_format_str[prefix_length + format_string_length + 1] = '\0';
        va_start(ap, format_str);
        return printf(
                prefixed_format_str,
                (int) time(0),
                ap);

        va_end(ap);
}

int main()
{
    wrapped_printf("Hello world %d\n", 5678);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

See it [failing](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e9139f38749fb4c7) on Coliru.

Notes:

- Only *one* call must be made - but it can be either to `printf()` or `vprintf()`.
- One can use a large string buffer, `sprintf()` the prefix into it, then `sprintf()` the original arguments afterwards; but that's also not what I mean.
- I don't mind using compiler-specific code - but if you suggest that, please try covering more than a single compiler on more than a single platform - and especially GCC or clang on GNU/Linux with an AMD64 processor.

Answer (score 1):

It is totally not possible to *prepend* arguments to a `va_list` portably in plain C. It can be done for sure, but it would require compiler-level wizardry for **each architecture** and **compiler** and **calling-convention**.

For a portable way, a library like [libffi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12263745/in-c-given-a-variable-list-of-arguments-how-to-build-a-function-call-using-the) and a parser for the format strings...

---

I suggest that if possible you'd go for a [macro instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20639632/how-to-wrap-printf-into-a-function-or-macro), if you're lucky enough to be on C99+; then you can prepend `"%d "` to the format string with compile-time string catenation and add the number in the arguments rather easily. But the format  need to be a string literal for this.

Or if you really need to use a function then I don't get the restriction of not using `printf` separately for the prefix followed by  these - **the output would be line-buffered or fully-buffered so there would not likely be any difference.**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <time.h>

#define wrapped_printf_macro(f_, ...) \
    printf("%lld " f_, (long long)time(0), __VA_ARGS__)

int wrapped_printf(const char* format_str, ...)
{
    static const char* const prefix = "%d ";
    static const size_t prefix_length = 3;
    va_list ap;

    printf("%lld ", (long long int)time(0));
    va_start(ap, format_str);
    vprintf(format_str, ap);
    va_end(ap);
}


int main()
{
    wrapped_printf_macro("Hello world %d\n", 5678);
    wrapped_printf("Hello world %d\n", 5678);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: @einpoklum mine has *2* choices there. A macro *or* a wrapper. But of course you can do whatever you want.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I was having my own idea I guess :-) ... Note your second option breaks my requirement, of only issuing a single `printf()`...

Comment: Your requirement is rather odd anyway. What's the real reason? Asking how to do it? I told already - it is close to impossible to do portably

Comment: The real reason is that I'm working in an environment which has a printf-like function which isn't printf and does something hardware-specific, and I can't call it twice, just once.