# redefining a function with a template

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

How do I redefine a call like this via C preprocessor Instructions to snprintf?

```
sprintf_s<sizeof(dataFile)>(dataFile, arg2, arg3);
```

I tried this (which doesn't work):

```
#define sprintf_s<sizeof(x)>(args...) snprintf<sizeof(x)>(args)
```

Especially because I already need this for calls to sprintf_s without a template in the same files:

```
#define sprintf_s(args...) snprintf(args)
```

Comment: What is `dataFile`, and what do you think `sizeof(dataFile)` will do?

Comment: It isn't quite clear what exactly you want, but perhaps simply `#define sprintf_s snprintf` should help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [**mkrs** said in his/her answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47265306/817643), the preprocessor doesn't allow you to match template-like function invocations.

You don't need the preprocessor for this task - use a *variadic template* instead:

```
template <int Size, typename... Ts>
auto sprintf_s(Ts&&... xs)
{
    return snprintf<Size>(std::forward<Ts>(xs)...);
}
```

If `snprintf` uses [`va_arg`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic/va_arg), you will need a different kind of wrapper:

```
template <int Size>
void sprintf_s(char* s, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, s);
    snprintf(args);
    va_end(args);
}
```

See [How to wrap a function with variable length arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41400/how-to-wrap-a-function-with-variable-length-arguments) for more examples.

Comment: This unfortunately gives me the following compiler error:
comparison of distinct pointer types
('int (*)(char *__restrict, size_t, const char *__restrict, ...) throw()' (aka 'int (*)(char *__restrict, unsigned long, const char *__restrict, ...) throw()') 
and 
'int *')


I have to admit that I only started out with templates and still find them confusing from time to time.

Comment: @EXIT_FAILURE: ah, it uses `va_args`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41400/how-to-wrap-a-function-with-variable-length-arguments

Answer (score 3):

This is simply not supported by the preprocessor. The preprocessor is largely the same as the C preprocessor and C has no notion of templates.

Comment: OP Is asking for the C preprocessor, that is (hopefully) largely the same as the C preprocessor...

Comment: It is also tagged as C++. Invoking the C preprocessor for C++ code makes even less sense.

Comment: Do you have any idea how I could redirect this to the appropriate Linux function without rewriting the actual code?

Comment: why does it make less sense?? Also the preprocessor does not need to be aware of templates to make it subsitute some symbols resulting in a template call

Comment: The preprocessor identifies a macro as an alphanumeric string. You can have parentheses for arguments, but once the preprocessor sees `<`, the possibilities for substitution end.

Comment: hm.. I guess you are right, I have to do some rtfm. wasnt aware that `<` has a special meaning for the preprocessor